# how to merge tables based on a column in sas

Tags: sql, sas

I've multiple tables in SAS having a same column that I want to merge together as

```
table_1
obj_Id | value_txt
 1     |    T1
 2     |    T1
 3     |    T1

table_2
obj_Id | value_txt
 1     |    T2
 2     |    T2
 3     |    T2

table_3
obj_Id | value_txt
 1     |    T3
 2     |    T3
 3     |    T3
```

To Merge them as one I can do things as

```
proc sql noprint;
create table merge as
select t1.obj_id, t1.value_txt as T1, t2.value_txt as T2, t3.value_txt as T3 
from table_1 t1, table_2 t2, table_3 t3,
where t1.obj_id eq t2.obj_id
and   t1.obj_id eq t3.obj_id;
quit;
```

but in my actual scenario I've tables near 15-20 with more then 5K records in each table so this method becomes very slow and takes 5-7 minutes to process.

I'm looking for any better and fast approach to merge tables together as one table by a column.

Comment: Merge? What about `UNION ALL`?

Comment: group by obj_id?

Comment: Your code is slow because you're generating a cartesian product of three tables with thousands of rows each before filtering it down with a `where` condition. Use an explicit `join` of some sort in your query, or do a data step merge.

Comment: @user667489 what is data step merge?

Comment: Have a look at the link above for an example.

Comment: @user667489 Thanks, It worked and much faster then my previous code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the SAS SQL and Merge code below will create the same output:

```
/*SAS Inner Join*/
proc sql noprint;
create table merge as select 
t1.obj_id , t1.value_txt as T1, t2.value_txt as T2, t3.value_txt as T3 
from 
table_1 t1 inner join table_2 t2 on  t1.obj_id = t2.obj_id 
inner join  table_3 t3 on t1.obj_id = t3.obj_id;
quit;
/*SAS Data Step Megrge*/
data merge_sas;
 merge table_1(rename=(value_txt=T1)) table_2(rename=(value_txt=T2)) table_3(rename=(value_txt=T3));
 by obj_id;
 run;
```

Output:

[image: Merge Table]